# How to set label for decorator in Zend

Tags: php, jquery, html, zend-framework

I am needing to style my checkboxes in Zend framework, at the minute my zend form populates labels like so:

```
<dt id="disabled-label"><label for="disabled" class="optional">Disabled Access</label></dt>
<dd id="disabled-element">
<input type="hidden" name="disabled" value="0"><input type="checkbox" name="disabled" id="disabled" value="1"></dd>
```

I need it to output:

Disabled Access

Below is the zend form as it stands, obviously I have only given the shorter version of the HTML above:

```
    public function searchForm() {
        $sp = $this->createElement('checkbox', 'sw')
                ->setOptions(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Swimming Pool',
                )
        );

        $spa = $this->createElement('checkbox', 'spa')
                ->setOptions(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Spa ',
                )
        );

        $gym = $this->createElement('checkbox', 'gym')
                ->setOptions(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Gym ',
                )
        );

        $wifi = $this->createElement('checkbox', 'wifi')
                ->setOptions(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Wifi ',
                )
        );

        $parking = $this->createElement('checkbox', 'parking')
                ->setOptions(
                array(
                    'label' => 'On-Site Parking ',
                )
        );

        $golf = $this->createElement('checkbox', 'golf')
                ->setOptions(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Golf ',
                )
        );

        $wp = $this->createElement('checkbox', 'wp')
                ->setOptions(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Wedding Packages ',
                )
        );

        $cc = $this->createElement('checkbox', 'cc')
                ->setOptions(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Civil Ceremonies ',
                )
        );

        $city = $this->createElement('checkbox', 'city')
                ->setOptions(
                array(
                    'label' => 'City Central ',
                )
        );

        $oot = $this->createElement('checkbox', 'oot')
                ->setOptions(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Out Of Town ',
                )
        );

        $disabled = $this->createElement('checkbox', 'disabled')
                ->setOptions(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Disabled Access ',
                )
        );

        $submit = $this->createElement('submit', 'submit')
                                ->setOptions
                                (array('label' => 'SEARCH OUR HOTELS',
                                       'class' => 'f-left btn-purple icon'
                                    ));

        $this->addElement($sp)
                ->addElement($spa)
                ->addElement($gym)
                ->addElement($wifi)
                ->addElement($parking)
                ->addElement($golf)
                ->addElement($wp)
                ->addElement($cc)
                ->addElement($city)
                ->addElement($oot)
                ->addElement($disabled)
                ->addElement($submit);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `dtddWrapper` decorator using :

```
$element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
```

But it will still add `<label for...>` tag.

Or you can add your own decorator... See [this post](http://www.zendcasts.com/creating-custom-zend_form-decorators/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `->setLabelAttributes(array(''))`